# I am trying to install axios but such error occured

Tags: npm, axios, react-native, npm-install

**Command:** `npm install --save axios`

I am unable to install `axios`. I am using `reactnative` in windows and want to make a HTTP request

**Error**

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.3 (node_modules\sane\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! path D:\reactnative\albums\node_modules\.staging\axios-29ec864b
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\reactnative\albums\node_modules\.staging\axios-29ec864b' -> 'D:\reactnative\albums\node_modules\axios'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\reactnative\albums\node_modules\.staging\axios-29ec864b' -> 'D:\reactnative\albums\node_modules\axios']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'D:\\reactnative\\albums\\node_modules\\.staging\\axios-29ec864b',
npm ERR!   dest: 'D:\\reactnative\\albums\\node_modules\\axios',
npm ERR!   parent: 'albums' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Turn off antivirus and try installation of module again

Comment: According to your error message you don't have permission to do this.Run your command prompt as Administrator

Comment: I'm running CMD as administrator only! Yet not working

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall axios by this commands:

1. npm uninstall axios
2. npm i axios

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But it was easy to solve. I believe you have first created your project with `npm init`. This created a file `package.json`. Please verify if this file is open somewhere. In my case i closed the package.json and did a

```
npm install --save axios
```

again. Do not forget to commit the created `package-lock.json`
Let me know if this helps
Cheer Mchoeti

Answer (score 0):

Run command as administrator
1-if it still doesn't work then uninstall axios package by type "npm uninstall axios"
2- then close the node.js terminal 
3- open command as administrator then go to the path then reinstall it "npm install axios"
4- then run the server again "react-native run-android"
it should works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Axios React js**

1. Go to Folder holds All Packages (**npm**) As **src** , **public** , **node-modules**

[image]

2. Right Click and Select **Open in Integrated Terminal**
3. Write in Terminal **npm install axios**

[image]

4. **Package.json**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in windows try to open the terminal as administrator then go in your app in node_modules folder and run:
npm install axios --force

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing same problem
Just go to your package-lock.json and there is fsevents,simply you can remove **"optional": true** from there and then reinstall axios. It will work fine!

"fsevents":
{
"version": "2.1.3",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.1.3.tgz",
"integrity":
"sha512Auw9a4AxqWpa9GUfj370BMPzzyncfBABW8Mab7BGWBYDj4Isgq+cDKtx0i6u9jcX9pQDnswsaaOTgTmA5pEjuQ==",

"dev": true,

"optional": true// remove this line
},

Comment: package-lock.json shouldn't be modified directly. It's a file that captures the dependency tree at the moment. 

And please use markups to present your answer in a prettier way.

Comment: @MikayelSaghyan got it.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to install axiuos and ran into this error after trying the solution here by Mchoeti

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/axious - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'axious@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kusumarajesh/.npm/_logs/2022-02-09T04_04_50_334Z-debug.log